# Mongoengine querying whether a ListField contains at least one element from another list

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have the following model in mongoengine -

```
class Job(Document):
   heading = StringField(required = True)
   skills = ListField(StringField(), default = [])
```

I want to query all `Job`s which have a skill present in another variable called `user_skills`

For example, let's say we have three jobs -

```
Job1 - skills: ['C', 'C++', 'Java']
Job2 - skills: ['Python', 'Ruby', '.NET']
Job3 - skills : ['Testing', 'HTML', 'JavaScript']
```

And the `user_skills` is a variable with the values - `['C', 'Java', 'Python']`.

I want to fetch all `Jobs` whose skills contains at least one matching skill with `user_skills` which in this case will be `Job1` and `Job2`.

How do I form such a query in Mongoengine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` operator in query.

```
Job.objects(skills__in=user_skills)
```

Where `user_skills` should be your list to match

**For further querying**

check https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/querying.html